# PHP, Creating File in Directory

Tags: php, file, text, directory, text-files

Help!

So I've look at many solutions of this on stack overflow, but non seem to have worked. So what I'm doing is creating a directory with a random number, then creating a text file in it.

My directory is like this:

```
localhost
--/tdir/
---/(random number directory) < this is were i want to save to the text file
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
            $dir = rand(1, 1999999);
            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        }
            if ($dir == true) {
                echo "Created directory! :D";
            } else {
                echo "Failed to create directory! ~ :(";
            }

        chmod("/tdir/$dir/", 0777);
        echo "</br><a href='/tdir/'>Go Back</a>";
        echo "</br><a href='/tdir/$dir'>Go to page!</a></br>";
        $my_file = '../'.$dir.'/file.txt';
        $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
        $data = 'This is the data';
        fwrite($handle, $data);
    ?>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Created directory! :D
Go Back
Go to page!
Cannot open file: ../1320710 *random number directory* /file.txt
```

**I need to be able to save to file.txt in the $dir directory!**

Comment: You aren't actually checking if the directory was created. `$dir` is just a random number, and it will always evaluate to `TRUE`, so your condition `if ($dir == true) {` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate the response of the mkdir function, just write it like this

```
if (mkdir($dir, 0777, true) === TRUE){
....
```

Also, when writing/reading folders, make sure that you use System path, not URL path.